# How to add c++11 features to visual studio 2013?

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I have got myself a copy of VS 2013 professional and I've been quite happy with this IDE, however one downvside that have been annoying me for a while is that some features that I can easily use with g++ such as `vector<string> s{ "a", "b", "c", "d" };` won't compile with VS compiler. I think it has something to do with VS not using c++1x?
Can someone please tell me how to add these features to VS?

Comment: Install a newer version of VS...

Comment: I have downloaded the The November 2013 CTP . it solved the `consexpr` problem but not the vector initializing problem :(

Comment: That's not the most recent version, there are CTP versions of 2015.